# How to install Angrybirds in Ubuntu 14.10 with Wine?

Tags: software-installation, wine, games, winetricks

I'm a great fan of Ubuntu and Angrybirds.But I never got these two together !
Is there a way to install Angrybirds in Ubuntu ?
Its not a problem to use Wine or not.
But I need to play Angrybirds !
Please help me...

Comment: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNTO4IgCuEw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Play it online from your browser (on [angrybird.com](http://chrome.angrybirds.com/) for example) or via the [chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/angry%20birds).
2. Buy and download the Windows game [here](http://download.angrybirds.com/) and install via wine as stated [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/play-angry-birds-under-wine-on-linux)

Comment: Unfortunately both variants have been discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

[Is there something like bluestacks for linux / ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607967/is-there-something-like-bluestacks-for-linux-ubuntu?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

You can use a virtual machine to run android 86x. And then play angry birds that way. This will also allow you to use any android game you wish.