# Is there something like bluestacks for linux / ubuntu?

Tags: android, kde-apps

http://www.bluestacks.com/ (runs Android apps on our PC / laptop) is not available for Linux. I am trying to run some android apps on my ubuntu. Many thanks :)

Comment: Google Chrome recently released a beta version of the ARC Welder extension for running Android apps in the latest version of Google Chrome (it can also be installed in Chromium web browser).

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/questions/279816/how-to-run-whatsapp-on-ubuntu?lq=1

Comment: Yes, There are alternate methods to install bluestacks on Linux: #1: use VirutalBox and Install Windows and Install Bluestacks in it ( which is slow) Or else use #2 Try Genymotion Guide to get Bluestacks Linux: https://www.watchmetech.com/download-bluestacks-linux-install/ and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 8):

You can run android x86 on virtual box. Android x86 can also run as standalone operating system on x86 computers. 
[Here is android x86](http://www.android-x86.org)
 [and VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org)

Comment: I tried this but it's too slow and not fast as blustark